# How to log each request to a csv file

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am developing a REST API and I want to write all the calls to a csv file . So I use the [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library and i wrote the below code:

```
   CSVWriter writer;

   Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@RequestMapping(value="/data",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getdata(@RequestParam("id")int id,@RequestParam("user")String user) throws IOException{             
            String[] log = new String[1];
            log[0]=id+","+"+user+","+new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())+",";
            writer.writeNext(log);

            writer.flushQuietly();
                //....rest code here 

return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(resultMap,HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

But this only prints a few and does not print all the requests to csv.Why does this happen? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's better if you log them in separate log file. Check logger integration.

Comment: But the amount of file will be more since the request are more. And by the end if it is one file it will be easy to import that one file as csv to a data base if needed.

Comment: @Ricky - but if your API receives many calls, and every call needs to await writing something to the CSV file, it can become a serious bottleneck. cody123 is right, check how to do proper logging.

Comment: But It doesn't take much time to write a line in a csv and if I am correct do you mean `logger.info("api call requests" )` as a proper logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest is just replacing the CSVWriter with a FileWriter and see if you have the same issue.  This should not be a problem as you are not really logging as a csv file but a csv file with one column that has commas in it.

Is your service multi threaded?  If so change your code so the csv logging portion is done in a synchronize block:

```
        synchronize(this) {
           String[] log = new String[3];

           log[0] = id;
           log[1] = user;
           log[2] = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

           writer.writeNext(log);
           writer.flushQuietly();
        }
```

The reason being is that I am wondering if there is an concurrency issue going on and this way only one thread can be logging at a time.